# Can I put a 2.3 mountain bike tire on what now has a 2.10 tire. 26 inch

Tags: tire, wheels, rims

I do see room for a 2.3 in front but in the
rear, I don't think I could go any higher than 2.20 or 2.25. Both rims currently have 2.10 tires on a 2006 Santa Cruz Blur

Comment: get a ruler or your measuring tool of choice and measure the physical clearance in both the tread direction and the sidewalls. also, inch-measurements of tires are vague. inspect the tire if it has a labeled number like "559-XX".

Comment: "probably"  but go read the canonical answer at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle). Also we have one about differing tire sizes front and back to cope with this situation (which is OK if you want to do it)

Comment: Mattnz might be referring to an old question of mine, which despite the title discusses exactly this issue: [How can I fit a bigger rear tyre when limited by the front derailleur?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/51994/7309). I ended up with 2.3" on the front and 2.1" on the back, carefully chosen for the conditions round here. It's a great improvement over the previous tyres (both 2.1", but less suited to mud)

Answer (score 1):

In terms on the rims/wheels, you certainly can.

In terms on the frame and forks, you have to make sure that you have enough clearance for the tyre, plus extra room for the wheel to wobble a bit (wheels/tyres distort during normal use, how much depends on wheels, brakes, frame etc) and room for mud/dirt/ other things.

You also have to consider whether the front derailleur (if you have on) will hit the tyre during use.

I would personally not use a tyre if the clearance on each side is 5mm.

EXTRA:

[Wheel wobble link 1](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31075/rear-wheel-rubs-frame-cage-while-pedaling-standing-up) They have issues with tyre rub, possibly due to weak wheel

[Wheel wobble link 2](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45694/big-tires-are-rubbing-in-certain-conditions-so-how-can-i-fix-my-rear-wheel-play) They have issues with tyre rub after increasing tyre width